# How can I change default ALT shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, 19.04, settings

There's an option to change the shortcut of <kbd>ALT</kbd>, like in Windows. I use to write superscript <kbd>²</kbd> by press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> but in here in Ubuntu if I press any number with <kbd>ALT</kbd> it takes me to that tab.

Tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

How do I write superscript <kbd>²</kbd> with <kbd>ALT</kbd> combination in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key while typing <kbd>2</kbd>

You then will get superscript ² as required.

[image]

FWIW ³  ½  ¾ are also available from pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> with <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> respectively (and there are others too to experiment with).

Some keyboards do not come equipped with the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key (such as the French AZERTY keyboard) and in that case a useful work-around can be found in this resource: https://www.alt-codes.net/fraction-symbols from which you can hover over the symbol you require, left click with the mouse which places the character in the clip board and then use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> or right mouse click and select to `Paste` where required in your text.

Comment: i don't have alt gr button in keyboard

Comment: @c7b3rx You don't mention which keyboard you have but I have amended my answer to provide an alternative since you don't have the AltGr key. PLease let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are confusing two different features.

Feature 1: Type unicode using default keyboard

Feature 2: Using Alt as a modifier for Unicode.

In windows, Alt does this. On Linux, it is done by Ctrl + Shit + U + (number).

So, to type ² on Linux, you do:

```
Ctrl + Shift + U + 00B2
```

Oh, and that's the other difference, on Linux, you need to type the hexadecimal code for that character, on Windows, it is in decimal.

I prefer the Linux way, as the entire Unicode keymap IS available in hex, so you just find the character code and type it in.